javascript and html google script to delete all text in google sheet
I want to make it so a HTML button will run a google script which will delete all the contents of a google sheet (the text). Can anyone explain to me how I can do this with the button and the javascript for the button as well as the script itself.
I haven't tried anything yet because I an not sure how to approach or do this!
